# Have 2 divs fill out the rest of the page

Tags: css, html, screen, fill

I'm currently working on a website, but it's important that it must fit on every page. I have 5 divs horizontal. The 3 divs in the middle are fixed sizes, 200 px, 400 px and again 200px. Now I have one on the far left and one of the far right, that should be equally big and fill out the screen no matter what resolution you're viewing the website in. So the middle part should be in the middle, and the 2 divs on the left and right of the middle part should fill out the screen. I have tried several techniques explained in other threads, but most are only for the left, or only for the right part and not working for both left and right. Maybe someone has a solution?

My HTML

```
<div id="left">
test
</div>
<div id="buttonsleft">
test
</div>
<div id="middle">
test
</div>
<div id="buttonsright">
test
</div>
<div id="right">
test
</div>
```

My CSS

```
#left{
    float:left;
    background-color:#C00;
    width:15%;
    height:100%;
}
#buttonsleft{
    float:left;
    background-color:#3F0;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
}
#middle{
    float:left;
    background-color:#30F;
    width:400px;    
    margin:auto;
}
#buttonsright{
    float:left;
    background-color:#3FF;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
}
#right{
    float:left;
    background-color:#300;
    width:15%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be easily done using the CSS table layout.
See that [**Working Fidde**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/Wd8AT/2/)

If the view port is smaller then 1000px wide, then the divs will shrink.
[you didn't specify what should happend if the view port is less then 1000px]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="Container">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="buttonsleft">buttonsleft</div>
    <div id="middle">middle</div>
    <div id="buttonsright">buttonsright</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
}
.Container
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.Container > div
{
    display: table-cell;
}
#left {
    background-color:#C00;
}
#buttonsleft {
    background-color:#3F0;
    width:200px;
}
#middle {
    background-color:#30F;
    width:400px;
}
#buttonsright {
    background-color:#3FF;
    width:200px;
}
#right {
    background-color:#300;
}
```

Comment: Well, I have specified that, the code snippet is just a small piece of the website I have now. This works very well thank you very much, but the code has brought me to a next problem. It scales perfectly, however the DIVs that were in #middle before, are now underneath it. I fear this is due to the .Container > div tag which puts all divs in cells right? Is there a way to do apply that only to these 5 divs so that the rest still functions?

Comment: Yes: It just was an easy way to apply this rule to all of them at once. I don't think I understood your new problem, If you don't succeed in resolving it, post the current HTML CSS you have, and I'll try to see..

Comment: I've uploaded the website, check the source to see what I have now. http://luukvanaggelen.com/test/index.html The problem is, the thing that now is underneath it used to be in the middle div (it still is codewise but not visual) Thanks for the reply man!

Comment: I think that it's because your content is bigger then the holder itself, causing the content to go down to a separate line. I see that the problem is only in FF(IE & Chrome works good). try giving `position:relative` to `.midden` and `position:absolute; top:0;` to his direct children.

Comment: I'm 100% certain all children have a position:absolute, yet nothing happens. I can put it back up giving it a top:-200px; or so, but that means that in IE and Chrome is goes up as well.. I'm also certain the content isn't actually bigger. I've read online its a common firefox problem, but like always all common solutions don't work for me...

Comment: emm, If I were you, I would go with a percentage based layout instead of Fixed PX. (I think the problem lay there..). Sorry I can't help you further..

Comment: No problem, you have been very helpful as is! Thanks for everything